# make sql command by date object python

Tags: python, mysql, string, date, pyodbc

I want to write a 'select' command of mysql through python and I want to use date-time object of python:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=aaa;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from tableA where time>" + str(CurrentTime)+ " order by time asc")
```

where type of CurrentTime is `datetime.datetime`.

When I print the above string, it looks fine, but when I run this, it gives me an error:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w)
>   Driver][mysqld-5.5.16-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '11:17:07 order by time asc' at line 1 (1064)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)")

Solved:
cursor.execute("""select * from tablea where time> ? order by time asc""" , str(CurrentTime))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameters:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=aaa;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from tableA where time > ? order by time asc",
               CurrentTime)
```

I don't have MySQL to test with, so maybe I'm missing something.